# I can't be logged in using Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

I cannot access my accounts in websites using Firefox 3.6.10
Internet Explorer and other browsers do well!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure firefox is set to accept cookies from the websites you're trying to log into. Most websites store that information in a cookie and will not be able to verify who you are if they can't store that identifying information on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a site that is designed for IE? My company has several internal sites that I can login only using IE and in those cases, I use a firefox extension called [IE Tab Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10909/) to use these websites.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old cookies of the site from firefox (http://www.aboutcookies.org/Default.aspx?page=2) and restart the firefox